# AF switch on lens vs. AF switch on camera

Tags: lens, autofocus

Is there any difference between using only the AF/MF switch on my camera (Nikon D90) or using the AF/MF switch on my lens (18-105mm)?

Could having autofocus on my camera switched to manual focus harm my equipment if the lens has autofocus turned on, or vice-versa?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't.

Nope, it won't harm your gear - if either switch is set to off, your AF will be off.

Comment: That being said, if your lens doesn't have a clutch to let you adjust focus manually, you might damage your lens if you turn off autofocus in-camera, leave the lens switched to A, and really crank on the focus ring.

Comment: Specifically for the D90, the (in)famous Ken Rockwell has a [guide to the D90s AF settings](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/d90/af-settings.htm).